# How to make string with no spaces wrap correctly inside of a dynamically sized div?

Tags: html, css

I currently have a div that looks like the following when a normal paragraph with spaces is inputted.  The letters “A”, “B” and “C” denote icons that I currently have in the div:

[image]

**The picture above demonstrates the correct behavior in the case where the paragraph has spaces**, since icon "C" is still inside of the div and there is space between icon "C" and the text.

However, problems occur when I attempt to put in a long string without spaces inside of the span with class “text”.  The long string wraps, but still pushes out icon “C” from the right side of the div and places its text over it:

[image]

These are the CSS attributes for the div with the class “text” in which the long text with no spaces is located:

```
.text {
  font-weight: normal;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

I am aware of the css attribute word-break: break-word, but unfortunately that attribute will not work in firefox if a parent div is using display:flex.  See this issue for more details:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1136818

How do I do the following?:

1. Make the long word wrap without pushing icon "C" out of the div?
2. Do #1 without using the word-break: break-word property which has a bug in firefox?

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AdUFfJpau6USBdm0FKvP?p=preview) for your convenience

```css
.goal {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: #23b389;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 20px;
  min-height: 60px;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.item-container .collapse-expander {
  margin-left: -20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.item-container > :not(.collapse-expander) {
  margin: 1px 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.item-container > :not(.collapse-expander):not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.text {
  font-weight: normal;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.standard-icon {
  color: #1aa8de;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-icon {
  color: #1aa8de;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
<br>
<br>
<div class="goal">
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="collapse-expander">A</div>
      <div class="standard-icon">B</div>
      <div class="clickable">
        <span class="text">
ThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongwordThisisareallylongword
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="menu-icon">
        C
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `word-wrap: break-word;` use `word-break: break-word;`

Like this

```
.text {
  font-weight: normal;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

And `word-break: break-all;` seems to work on most of the firefox versions. So try using `break-all` instead of `break-word`.

This should work on most of the firefox verisons

```
.text{
word-break: break-all;
white-space: pre-wrap;
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: That would normally be the easiest way of solving this issue, but  unfortunately that attribute will not work in some versions of firefox if a parent div is using display:flex. See this issue for more details:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1136818

Comment: Then you should try adding 'white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;' to the 'text' class.